# Is there a way to express 'infinite time'?

Tags: ruby, datetime, range

I am using the [`Range`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html) class to represent a range of times. Now I want a range which represents any point after a given time.

I tried `(DateTime.now .. nil)`, but the `Range` class doesn't allow objects of different classes to be endpoints of the same range. (Attempting to create a `Range` with this property results in `ArgumentError: bad value for range`.)

Is there an equivalent of infinity for time, i.e. `Time.now + (1.0/0.0)`? Or alternately, is there a way to get around the `Range` class's requirement that its `min` and `max` values be of the same class?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It's possible using `DateTime::Infinity` class:

```rb
future = DateTime.now..DateTime::Infinity.new
future.include?(1_000_000.years.from_now) #=> true
```

Comment: Hey, it works! Interesting that there doesn't seem to be any documentation on this. The documentation for [DateTime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.5/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html) doesn't mention an Infinity class at all.

The only problem with this approach is that it doesn't seem to work for "negative" infinity. This works: `DateTime.now > (-DateTime::Infinity.new)`, but `((-DateTime::Infinity.new)..(DateTime::Infinity.new)).include? DateTime.now` does not, and `(-DateTime::Infinity.new) < DateTime.now` raises an exception.

Comment: Also, for the example in this answer to work, you need to require `date` and `active_support/core_ext`.

Comment: Negative infinity: DateTime::Infinity.new(-1)

Comment: DateTime::Infinity.new(-1) doesn't seem to work with ranges: DateTime::Infinity.new(-1)...DateTime.now gives ArgumentError: bad value for range

Comment: @AndrewKS `DateTime::Infinity.new(-1)...DateTime.now` does not work because of [rails issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8178)

Answer (score 9):

```ruby
range = (Time.now.to_f .. Float::INFINITY)
range.include?(Time.now.to_f) # => true
sleep 1
range.include?(Time.now.to_f) # => true
range.include?(Float::INFINITY) # => true
```

Comment: Ah, I could represent the time as a float; I guess that could work.

Comment: Just don't try to convert the range to an array. You'll wait a long time.

Comment: @the Tin Man, actually .to_a on a range with floats never works.  You get `TypeError: can't iterate from Float`.  :)

Answer (score 1):

When you need to represent infinite time, you could use an object from a different class, that you create yourself.  Just implement the matching operator and any other methods you use, and then it can be used interchangeably with Range objects.

```
class TimeRange
    def initialize(min, max)
    ...
    end
end
```