# Rails `where` for time less than queries

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails, date, arel

## Setup

Rails' `where` method can take a range in a hash to generate a query that will search for a value that is within the range. For example:

```
User.where(cash_money: 10..1000)
#=> SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (`users`.`cash_money` BETWEEN 10 AND 1000)
```

This can also be used with timestamps like

```
User.where(last_deposit: 10.days.ago..1000.days.ago)
#=> SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (`users`.`last_deposit` BETWEEN '2014-05-19 14:42:36' AND '2011-09-02 14:42:36')
```

I've found that you can do a simple less than or greater than with numbers using the hash syntax like this

```
User.where(cash_money: 10..Float::INFINITY)
#=> SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (`users`.`cash_money` >= 10)
```

and the same can be done with `-Float::INFINITY` for less than queries.

## Question

Is there a way to do this with timestamps so I can get a query like the following?

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (`users`.`last_deposit` >= '2014-05-19 14:42:36')
```

I cannot use `Float::INFINITY` or `Date::Infinity` with a range as they both error with `ArgumentError: bad value for range`.

## Current Simple Solution

```
User.where('`users`.`last_deposit` >= ?', 10.days.ago)
```

will generate the same SQL but if this can be done with objects other than strings, I'd like to do so.

## Potential (Meh) Answer

This is kind of lousy but it could be done with ranges using `Time.at(0)` and `Time.at(Float::MAX)`. I have a feeling these could result in equally lousy SQL queries though.

Comment: One of my most loathed aspects of Active Record is no obvious and intuitive support for gt/lt-or-equals (or ranges) in where() clauses! Passing in strings like "column >= ?" just makes me wonder why I dont just type the query out myself in the first place.

Comment: My answer [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317662/rails-using-greater-than-less-than-with-a-where-statement/23936233#23936233) gives more details for the latest versions of Ruby and Rails as of this writing (3.0.2 and 6.1 respectively).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

## Edit 2 5/9/20

If you are using Ruby 2.6 you can do this with endless ranges and in Ruby 2.7 you can use begin-less ranges.

E.g.:

```rb
# Ruby >= 2.6
User.where(last_deposit: 10.days.ago..)
```

generates

```sql
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "user"."last_deposit" >= '2020-04-29 21:58:39.109419'"
```

and

```rb
# Ruby >= 2.7
User.where(last_deposit: ..10.days.ago)
```

generates

```sql
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."last_deposit" <= '2020-04-29 22:01:05.582055'
```

## Edit

This is now possible in Rails 5!

```
User.where(last_deposit: 10.days.ago..DateTime::Infinity.new)
```

will generate the SQL

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (`users`.`last_deposit` >= '2018-06-30 17:08:54.130085').
```

## Original (and Rails < 5) Answer

It does not appear as if there is a way to use basic `where` hash syntax to generate a greater than or less than query for timestamps. The simplest and most readable way is outlined in my question under `Current Simple Solution`.

Another way to do it makes use of ARel but you have to make some less commonly seen calls. First you can get a handle to the AR class' ARel table, access the column, pass the result of the greater than `gt`, greater than or equal to `gteq`, less than `lt`, and/or less than or equal to `lteq` method with an argument to `where`.

In the situation above this would be done like:

```
last_deposit_column = User.arel_table[:last_deposit]
last_deposit_over_ten_days_ago = last_deposit_column.gteq(10.days.ago)
User.where(last_deposit_over_ten_days_ago)
```

Comment: The verbosity is not necessary and _could_ be done on one line. I'm just using variables to make it explicitly clear what each step returns.

Comment: Using the syntax before `User.where(last_deposit: ..10.days.ago)`
Give me the exception syntax error, unexpected ')'

Comment: @ThangLeQuoc what version of Ruby are you on? `ruby --version`

Comment: I'm on `ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812)`

Comment: Endless ranges are in Ruby 2.6+ and beginless ranges were introduced in Ruby 2.7 so nothing is wrong with your system.

Answer (score 14):

Did you try this?:

```
User.where(last_deposit: Time.at(0)...10.days.ago)
```

SQL:

```
SELECT `users`.* FROM `users`  WHERE (`users`.`last_deposit` >= '1970-01-01 00:00:00' AND `users`.`last_deposit` < '2015-01-10 17:15:19')
```

Comment: That works decently for `User.where('`users`.`last_deposit` < ?', 10.days.ago)` but not for the `>=` case I wanted. Switching it to `10.days.ago...Time.at(Float::INFINITY)` also doesn't work. It generates SQL but an invalid date (at least for PG).

Comment: Three dots between the range-limits gets you a >= on the 'from' value with 'AND <' on the 'to' value .  Two dots gets you a 'BETWEEN' sql query using 'from' and 'to'. (in Rails 4.0.13)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the appropriate infinity. A timestamp is a `DateTime` not a `Date`. Use `DateTime::Infinity.new` instead or `DateTime::Infinity.new(-1)` for negative infinite.

Related: [Is there a way to express 'Infinite Time' in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567639/is-there-a-way-to-express-infinite-time-in-ruby)

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about `Datetime::Infinity`. It's odd that it must be instantiated as `Float::INFINITY` does not. I realize that one is a constant for a Float value and the other is a class but it would be easier to remember if it were symmetric.

Comment: I can confirm that it does not work with Rails 4 though. `User.where(created_at: 1.day.ago..DateTime::Infinity.new)` results in a MySQL error as it has `#<Date::Infinity:0x0...>` as the ending bound instead of converting to use `>` or something else.

Comment: Odd, could be a MySQL thing. Oh well, cases like this I just use the far future and/or far past when infinity isn't working well enough. `User.where(created_at: 1000.years.ago..1000.years.from_now)`. Though that's not much better than the `Time.at()` solutions. Tried converting to to dateTIme, but got similarly odd errors. Might also find it interesting to note that `User.where(created_at: 1.day.ago.to_date..Float::INFINITY)` works.

Comment: Are you on Rails 5 by chance? My gut says the fact that as the query goes from Ruby objects to an SQL string it's not being converted properly to something a database would understand hence the Ruby object's inspect output of `#<Date::Infinity:0x0...object_address>` format. This could've been updated in Rails 5 which is why it works in some cases.

Comment: Quite possible, I have apps in Rails 4 and 5. Though unsure if that's the issue. Something to look into.

Comment: Could you provide any valid range with `DateTime::Infinity.new(-1)`? All my attempts failed.

Answer (score 0):

Rails 5 (and ruby < 2.7)

`User.where(last_deposit: 10.days.ago.to_datetime..DateTime::Infinity.new)`

that should also work:
`User.where(last_deposit: 10.days.ago..DateTime::Infinity.new)`

but problematic scope for condition before some date:

`User.where(last_deposit: DateTime::Infinity.new..10.days.ago.to_datetime)`

DateTime::Infinity.new right now is equal to Float::INFINITY.
Time.current (so 3.minutes.ago also) does not support range with Float.

Converting it to datetime solves the issue

Comment: @bonafernando 

`irb> (Float::INFINITY..Time.current.to_datetime).include? 2.days.ago.to_datetime`


`=> false`


`irb> (-Float::INFINITY..Time.current.to_datetime).include? 2.days.ago.to_datetime`


`=> true`


This does not work with `DateTime::Infinity.new`

Only one range I did with DateTime Infinity is useless:

`irb> (-DateTime::Infinity.new..DateTime::Infinity.new).include? 2.days.ago.to_datetime`


`=> false`


`irb> (DateTime::Infinity.new(-1)..DateTime::Infinity.new).include? 2.days.ago.to_datetime`


`=> false`

Comment: While your examples in you comment are correct usage in a query actually has nothing to do with inclusion in the range. Instead it has to do with how `Arel` used to handle between logic [Source](https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/v9.0.0/lib/arel/predications.rb#L28). You can see it directly relied on `Float::INFINITY`....

Comment: Newer iterations of `Arel` (now part of rails) changed this to be more flexible by relying on messages like `infinite?` and `boundable?` [Source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/arel/predications.rb#L37) which makes a lot more sense and it means you can create your own objects to pass in if you so desire.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
User.where(last_deposit.gt(10.days.ago))
```

Comment: Wouldn't `last_deposit` have to be an ARel column reference for this to work?

Comment: `last_deposit = User.arel_table[:last_deposit]` I believe.

Comment: As it stands, this answer is incomplete / incorrect - See Aaron's comments.