# How can I save an infinite date range to Postgres in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using:
Rails 5.2.3
Ruby 2.6.3
PostgreSQL 11.2

I have a model Foo with a field effective_date_range, here is the migration to create:

```
class CreateFoos < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :foos do |t|
      t.daterange :effective_date_range
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I get an error trying to create a record with an endless date range:

```
Foo.create(effective_date_range: (Date.today...nil))
> RangeError: cannot get the last element of endless range
```

Ruby 2.6.3 and Postgres 11.2 both support unlimited ranges. How can I get ActiveRecord to talk nice to Postgres?

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55642198/problems-with-infinite-time-range-in-rails
I'm afraid date and far-future is the only option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
Foo.create(effective_date_range: (Date.today...Date::Infinity.new))
```

The value in PostgreSQl will look like this: `[2019-11-27,)`.

Comment: are you sure it will be stored, I don't think so.

Comment: yes, it does. Tested with ruby 2.5.5, rails 5.1.7, postgres 9.6

Comment: so I just discovered that while this works: `Date.today...Date::Infinity.new`, this gives me an error: `(-Date::Infinity.new)...Date.today` - `*** ArgumentError Exception: bad value for range`.

Answer (score 0):

But WHY do you need infinity?  Can you just do something like:

```
[*Date.today..(300.years.from_now).to_date]
```

Or maybe just

```
range = [Date.today, Date.new(2300,1,1)]
```

If your program is still relevant in 2300, call me.  Until then, I'll be waiting. :)

Comment: Looking for infinity is likely to make the sysadmin or DBA descend on him for killing the system's response time. Storing and searching for `>=` a start date seems safer.

Comment: I will need to make Foo's behavior and that of any object that interacts with Foo conditional on the existence of the limit, in addition to its actual value. I would like the code's purpose to be easily understood by looking at it. I could create a value for the limit thats 300 years in the future, but that requires any object that interacts with Foo to know the specific value I’ve chosen to represent a nonexistent limit. But both Ruby and Postgres support an unlimited date range. I trust Ruby and Postgres to implement this data structure without needing to count to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer the accepted answer, but this also works and might prove useful if someone is working with different versions of Ruby/Rails/Postgres:

```
Foo.create(effective_date_range: "[#{Date.today.to_s(:db)},)")
```